# Appending and removing checkbox to div using checkbox/link

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, append

I am using jquery to append the value of a checkbox to an unordered list. What I can't work out is how I would remove the items from the lists again (toggle) only using the li as the clickable link rather than the uncheck as such of the checkbox.

I have included the html and Jquery below:

```
  function(){
$('.chkbox').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         text = $(this).val();
         price = $(this).data('price');
         $('<li />').appendTo('#addedtolist ul').text($(this).val());
        } 
          else {
           $('li a').click(function() {
           $('ul.summary a').remove();
           return false;
            });
}

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: {'name': text,'price':price },
            success: function(msg) {

                }
            });  
        }
    }); 
});
```

HTML

```
  <div id="addedtolist">
 <ul class='summary'>

 <li class="pink">Summary</li>

 <?php 
 $totalprice = 0;
 $totalprice = $ingredient['price'] + $totalprice;

 if (is_array($_SESSION['ingredients'])){
     foreach ($_SESSION['ingredients'] as $ingredient) {?>
     <li><span class="truncate"><?php echo $ingredient['name'] ;?></span>
      <strong>£<?php echo $ingredient['price'] ;?></strong>
      <a href="#">remove</a></li>
     <?php  $totalprice = $ingredient['price'] + $totalprice;


      }

     }
      echo "</ul>
      </div>";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks,
Mel

Comment: Your question "_lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem._" Where is `ul.summary` in your markup? Note that binding handlers within other handlers results in unexpected behaviors. Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) using all the relevant  code?

Comment: Sorry, I have included the full html- I hope this helps. Thank you.